# Add Buttons in Java

Tags: java, button, actionlistener

```
     import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;  

public class MenuDemo extends eikona
{ 

 private JProgressBar progress; 

 public MenuDemo(String title) 
 { 
 super(title); 
 Container contentPane = this.getContentPane(); 

 MenuColorChanger changer = new MenuColorChanger(contentPane, progress); 

 createMenu(changer); 
 } 

 public void createMenu(MenuColorChanger changer) 
 { 

 JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar(); 
 this.setJMenuBar(menuBar); 

 JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Options"); 

  menuBar.add(fileMenu); 

 JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Reset"); 
 fileMenu.add(exit); 
 exit.addActionListener(changer); 


 } 

 public static void main(String [] args) 
 { 
 MenuDemo f = new MenuDemo("MenuDemo"); 
 f.setSize(300,300); 
 f.setVisible(true); 
 } 
}
```

Hallo . i Got the upper code.. how can i put the buttons in specific positions???Well, i put button, but they go in specific places. How can i change them??? im pretty new at java so explain as better as you can please..

Comment: Please specify what you tried and what failed. Also check out basic Swing tutorials on basic layouts.

Comment: the buttons i make are going on specific places, how can i make them go in other?

Answer (score 0):

> how can i put the buttons in specific positions???

You don't.

You let the layout manager determine the location of size of each button. If you don't like the current layout, then you use a different layout manager. Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Since you haven't specified how you want the layout to work we can't give you any more specific information. So read the tutorial and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the buttons on the menubar, you can only change the order of those buttons so you can put reset before the options menu item. The order of the menu items are displayed in the order you place them in your code. You can also make buttons instead of having a menubar. Those buttons can be displayed in any position you would like by using different layouts.

Here is a sample code that I came up with using buttons. I like to use SpringLayout cause I think its a very simple layout and you can place the buttons in any position you would like too. Like I said you can choose any layout you are comfortable with.

Check out this site for more layouts: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

```
public class Buttons {

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(layout);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, button1, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, button1, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Button2");
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, button2, 40, SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, button2, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);

    contentPane.add(button1);
    contentPane.add(button2);

    frame.add(contentPane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);

}
}
```